# how to find turning points of a quartic function using calculus?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

My teacher gave a function of 
$$f(x)= 2x^4-3x^3-21x^2+16x+60$$
He said that there needs to be $4$ turning points. I only now how to find the turning points if the function is at cubic not quartic.

Comment: Did you try differentiating and setting the derivative $=0$?

Comment: I'm not sure. This topic is new so I really have no idea what to do

Comment: Do you know how to work out $f'(x)$?

Comment: No. I'm pretty hopeless at this. I'm not really good with math or other terms related to it.

Comment: To be honest, it is difficult to help you with this if you do not know how to differentiate. I suggest you practice differentiating simple functions on Khan Academy or similar before attempting this question.

Comment: What is your definition of 'turning point'? Many people have interpreted it as a point of 'inflection point' where $f''(x) = 0$, but you can also interpret it as where the function 'turns' or where $f'(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

There are at most three turning points for a quartic, and always at least one.

At a turning point (of a differentiable function) the derivative is zero. However the derivative can be zero without there being a turning point. (Consider $f(x)=x^3$ or $f(x)=x^5$ at $x=0$).

A good strategy for kinds of functions you don't completely understand is to sketch them - this works well for polynomials. What is the general shape of a quartic with positive coefficient of $x^4$?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition, 'turning point' can be an informal name for 'stationary point' ([mathsisfun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/polynomials-behave.html)). If you wish to find the stationary points, you will need the derivative:

$$f'(x) = 8x^3-9x^2-42x+16$$

To find the turning points, you can use the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), which says that the numerator must be a factor of $16$, and the denominator a factor of $8$. There are only a few possibilities, and using this we find that $-2$ is a root.

Using this, we can divide $f'(x)$ by $x+2$ to get a quadratic. You can use [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) to do this.  Now solve the quadratic to get all three $x$-coordinates of the stationary points, and then substitute them into the original to get the $y$-coordinates.

---

If you wish to find $f''(x)$ instead, you have that:

$$f''(x) = 0 \Rightarrow 24x^2-18x-42 =0$$

This is just a quadratic. You can simplify by taking a common factor, and then this quadratic should be factorisable.

Comment: what method do i use in order to get 3 x-coordinates?

Comment: You have that $x=2$ by the rational root theorem. Dividing $f'(x)$ by $x-2$ gives the other two roots, since the other factor is a quadratic. You should use the quadratic formula to do this, since you will find the quadratic cannot be factored.

Comment: I get $f'(x)=8x^3-9x^2-42x+16$.

Comment: That was a silly mistake, thanks. The rest of the post should not be affected.

Comment: I don't get $f'(2)=0$.